# Leptos - template not reactive with struct

Tags: rust, webassembly, leptos

In the code below, there are two instances where the `task.title` is being displayed, one using `task_title` (a memoized value) and the other directly from `task.get().title`. However, only the memorized value (task_title) updates when the input field's value changes.

Leptos doc seems to recommend use the `RwSignal` for the field inside the struct, is there any alternative to this problem?

The `Task` struct in the example come from an external crate, I want to avoid duplicating that to use internal Signal.

```rs
use leptos::*;
use leptos_meta::*;
use leptos_router::*;

#[component]
pub fn App() -> impl IntoView {
    provide_meta_context();

    view! {
        <Stylesheet id="leptos" href="/pkg/web-api.css"/>
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" view=HomePage/>
                <Route path="/test" view=Test/>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Task {
    id: Option<i64>,
    title: String,
    description: Option<String>,
}

#[component]
fn HomePage() -> impl IntoView {
    let (task, set_task) = create_signal(Task {
        id: None,
        title: "teste".to_string(),
        description: Some("".to_string()),
    });

    let task_title = create_memo(move |_| task.get().title.clone());
    view! {
        <div>
            <h1>HomePage</h1>
            {task_title} <<<<< update when changed
            <hr/>
            {task.get().title} <<<<< doenst change when updated
            <hr/>
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    prop:value=task.get().title
                    on:input=move |e| {
                        let new_title = event_target_value(&e);
                        set_task
                            .set(Task {
                                id: task.get().id,
                                title: new_title,
                                description: task.get().description.clone(),
                            });
                    }
                />

            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I figure out, I had to add a closure on the `{move || task.get().title}`